# Is damage reduction applied before Unity splits damage, or after?

Tags: diablo-iii

There's a ring, [Unity](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/unity), that splits damage among all people wearing it.

When does damage reduction apply for this?

Let's say, for example, I've got a barbarian loaded up with armor and resists who is sitting in a molten pool that does 50,000 damage per second, but with all his damage reduction he's got 90% resistance so it drops to like 5k/sec and he pretty much ignores it. Now let's say he and a mage friend of his put Unity on. Let's say the mage only has 50% damage reduction. When Unity splits the damage, is it going to be doing damage to the mage **after** the Barbarian's reduction (so, 2.5k/second) or will it be doing it before the Barbarian's reduction (so potentially 12.5k/second)?

Comment: I think in the final case, the wizard would take potentially 12.5k/second, not 25k/second. Half of half of 50k.

Comment: Won't be an answer but since we're talking about unity, a good tips  is to put a unity on you and one on your follower and a legendary follower item (follower can not die) : you get permanently 50% dmg reduction. For your question the last option seems the good one but I can't tell for sure

Comment: @Studoku good point, I actually use this only for boss fight

Comment: Whatever the answer: if it is an advantage in one direction, it will be a disadvantage in the other direction.

Comment: @wizliz that's actually what motivated me asking. I want to know if I'd suffer from my follower's crappy DR.

Comment: It would be very amusing if your followers pop out via Asheara's set bonus (and they all have unities) and there's someone else in the party wearing one of those rings and they instantly explode due to the crappy DR of followers.

Comment: After some veerification, the orange affixe of the relic "Your follower can not die" has for real effect "your follower doesnt take damage anymore" which mean you actually get 50% damage reduction. Not sure its working as intendend by Blizzard though, it might get fixed.

Comment: @WizLiz fwiw bliz confirmed this is intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The damage splitting effect works like this: For this example an
>   attack does 100 damage, Player A's damage mitigation is 70% and Player
>   B's is 50%.
>
> - When A gets hit, the attack is reduced to 30 damage, then gets halved    and both players take 15 damage.
> - When B gets hit, the attack is reduced to 50 damage, then gets halved    and both players take 25 damage.
> - If there are 3 Players & A gets hit, the resulting 30 damage will    result in each Player taking 10 damage.

As you can [see](http://www.diablohub.com/database/item/unity/information/),damage reduction is applied before the damage splits up(as true damage).